# Xcode5 cmd-line tests - simulator, device, and OSX

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos, xcodebuild

Xcode5 includes better support for cmd-line tests. For example, I can run iOS tests with the following:

**Simulator Tests**

```
xcodebuild -workspace ${module.name}.xcworkspace test -scheme ${module.name} -destination OS=7.0,name=iPhone -destination-timeout=10 -configuration Debug
```

**Device Tests**

And it is now possible to execute tests on the actual device hardware by specifying the device's name:

```
xcodebuild -workspace ${module.name}.xcworkspace test -scheme ${module.name} -destination id=${device.name} -destination-timeout=10 -configuration Debug
```

**OSX Tests**

What is the correct cmd-line for executing OSX tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the man page you need to specify the platform as 'OS X' and optionally the arch which can be x86_64 (default) or i386, eg.

```
xcodebuild test -scheme {schemename} -destination platform='OS X',arch=x86_64
```

If you're just building with the default destination though i've also found that you can omit the destination flag entirely

Answer (score 1):

I use xcrun -sdk and pass the -sdk parameter as well. But apparently, the -destination is now mandatory to overwrite the project settings regarding to the last device target set on the xcode project.